# SOAP & IBM MQ JMS

Tags: jms, ibm-mq

I was looking at [this](http://www.trevoroconnell.com/2012/01/basic-send-message-to-mq-with-java-and.html) and [this](https://developer.ibm.com/messaging/learn-mq/mq-tutorials/develop-mq-jms/) and other stuff for MQ Topics.
These use JMS APIs. Fine.

If I would like to use SOAP for the message, is that possible without using http(s) i.e. Web Service? SOAP applies to more than http(s).

Comment: IBM MQ doesn't care what message you send.  SOAP is just xml, why couldn't you send it via MQ?

Comment: I was told by a colleague that we could put in SOAP content expiry metadata for messages. I am more a KAFKA person. This is new to me, get the concepts of course, but the nuances. @JoshMc

Comment: Message expiry is supported by IBM MQ and the JMS spec both.

Comment: @JoshMc  i believe we have some discussion pts tomorrow

Comment: @JoshMc  no need for soap then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually quite simple. Answer may be of help to other architects new to some of this.

As the comments state, SOAP is just XML. But the point here is IBM do not use SOAP for describing the message, whereas others tend to do just this, also in conjunction with JMS.